# Float16 slower than float32 in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm testing out my new NVIDIA Titan V, which supports float16 operations.  I noticed that during training, float16 is much slower (~800 ms/step) than float32 (~500 ms/step).

To do float16 operations, I changed my keras.json file to:

```
{
"backend": "tensorflow",
"floatx": "float16",
"image_data_format": "channels_last",
"epsilon": 1e-07
}
```

Why are the float16 operations so much slower?  Do I need to make modifications to my code and not just the keras.json file?

I am using CUDA 9.0, cuDNN 7.0, tensorflow 1.7.0, and keras 2.1.5 on Windows 10.
My python 3.5 code is below:

```
img_width, img_height = 336, 224

train_data_dir = 'C:\\my_dir\\train'
test_data_dir = 'C:\\my_dir\\test'
batch_size=128

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,   # randomly flip the images 
    vertical_flip=True) 

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

# Architecture of NN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3, 3), input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3),padding='same',kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

my_rmsprop = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-04, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=my_rmsprop,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training 
nb_epoch = 32
nb_train_samples = 512
nb_test_samples = 512

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples/batch_size,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_test_samples/batch_size)

# Evaluating on the testing set
model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples)
```

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this?

Comment: No.  I was able to get half-precision to work roughly 2x faster in pytorch, so the problem is not my hardware or my CUDA/cuDNN installations.  I have a hunch that ImageDataGenerator might be the problem and if the images were loaded in a different way then I might see better performance, but I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: probably related: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5592 they say it was fixed for tf in late May

Comment: Has this been solved? If not, file a bug on github

Comment: My recent tests (one or two months ago - that is october/2018) showed that float16 was not faster.

Comment: Curiously -- its also slower in numpy.

Comment: Just a guess, isn't there a `float16` to `float32` conversion and then back-conversion before returning the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to CUDA 10.0, cuDNN 7.4.1, tensorflow 1.13.1, keras 2.2.4, and python 3.7.3.  Using the same code as in the OP, training time was marginally faster with float16 over float32.

I fully expect that a more complex network architecture would show a bigger difference in performance, but I didn't test this.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of cuDNN](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#scaling-parameters) (section 2.7, subsection **Type Conversion**) you can see:

> **Note:** Accumulators are 32-bit integers which wrap on overflow.

and that this holds for the standard INT8 data type of the following: the data input, the filter input and the output.

Under those assumptions, @jiandercy is right that there's a float16 to float32 conversion and then back-conversion before returning the result, and `float16` would be slower.

Comment: Float16 is meant to be faster than float32 though.  The code in the question might be too small of a test such that the conversions overtake the performance gains of switching to float16.  However, I also tried this with deeper network (InceptionResnetV2) and got very similar results.