# float16 is much slower than float32 in tensorflow when do embedding_lookup_sparse

Tags: python, tensorflow

When run the following code on Nvidia GTX1080ti, if FLOAT_DTYPE=tf.float16, the run time is 0.61s, if FLOAT_DTYPE = tf.float32, the time is 0.26s. The timeline show that scatter_sub take up a large part of the time. Why float16 is so much slower than float32? Tensorflow version is 1.8.

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf

FLOAT_DTYPE = tf.float16

var = tf.get_variable("embedding", initializer = tf.ones(shape = [1000000, 5], dtype = FLOAT_DTYPE), dtype = FLOAT_DTYPE)
embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(var, [i for i in range(100000)])

w = tf.get_variable("w", shape = [5, 1], dtype = FLOAT_DTYPE)
z = tf.matmul(embeddings, w)

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3, epsilon = 1e-4)

g = tf.gradients(z, xs = [var])
train = opt.apply_gradients([(g[0], var)])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(10):
        sess.run(train)
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print 'Time: %f' % elapsed
```

Comment: Can't tell you whats wrong with your code, but in my (limited) experience when working in CUDA with half precision: they are not always faster, only for some specific operations.

Comment: You're [not alone in this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49782579/364696), though I don't know if there is an answer besides "float16 is primarily a memory optimization, not a compute optimization; there is no guarantee it's any faster".

Comment: Looks like [there was a bug, fixed in May](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5592). Is your tensorflow up to date?

Comment: To expand in my comment, if you have a 32bit processor, you need to do 32 bit operationts always, each instruction is 32 bits. Having a variable of 16bits does not make the processor use less bits, it will add 32 bits, just fill with zeroes the rest of the number

Comment: @ShadowRanger I upgraded tensorflow to 1.11.0, float16 is also much slower than float32

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's not a problem for me. I want to reduce the bandwidth when training in distributed mode, but the training time is longer when use float16. I found that the only bottleneck is scatter_sub op. Any idea about how to improve the op performance?

Comment: @Buzz I am not used to tensorflow, but AFAIK, training is not bandwidth limited, but compute limited, right? You need to read do forward and backward propagation with is arithmetic, not memory reading.The function you mention is an arithmetic function too, therefore unrelated to memory bandwidth.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yea, this is just a unit test, when run the whole project, the training speed is limited by bandwidth.

Comment: The GTX 1080 Ti is [much slower](https://www.microway.com/knowledge-center-articles/comparison-of-nvidia-geforce-gpus-and-nvidia-tesla-gpus/) with float16 compared to float32.